# UNDROP recovers a table created with no retention time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I create a table with explicit DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS zero, i.e. no time travel. UNDROP on a dropped table should not restore the table. However, it does!

```
create or replace table t1 (col1 string)
  DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS=0; -- yes, no time travel please
insert into t1 values ('abc');
drop table t1;
undrop table t1; -- hey, this works!
select * from t1; -- this returns my table with the row inserted!
```

Comment: Probably a good question for support at Snowflake.  It's possible that you are executing the queries fast enough to not allow the service layer to actually drop the MPs of that table, so Snowflake is allowing the undrop until that is done.

If you really don't want any data retention, I would recommend using a TRANSIENT table, instead.  This will avoid paying for the FAIL SAFE storage of that table, as well.

Comment: Hi @MikeWalton - it's a good point with the TRANSIENT tables, but this should still work. However, I think I found the problem. But I'll let more people comment first...

Comment: The suspense is killing me.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DROP TABLE will remove any explicit DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS you have set. The dropped table will now inherit whatever similar parameter value you have in the parent schema, database, or account. This is usually 1 by default. Or, in my case, it was 5 at the database level. Run **show tables history like 't1'**.

This means you've automatically got time travel, and all your data will now be saved, only when the table is dropped, with no other previous history data.

If you intend to drop tables and to rely on UNDROP, you should rather set the retention time parameter at the schema or database level:

```
create or replace database db1
  DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS=0; -- no time travel for any table here!
create or replace table t1 (col1 string); -- inherited, as zero
insert into t1 values ('abc');
drop table t1;
undrop table t1; -- now this fails, as expected
```

UNDROP fails now, as expected, with "*Table T1 does not exist or was purged*". Because t1 still inherits retention time 0 from its parent database.

Later Edit: if your database has no time travel, but your table has, expect to lose not just all historical data when you drop the table, but all table data as well. Which can not be restored.

Comment: This makes sense.  In your OP, had you deleted the record, it'd be immediately unrecoverable using time-travel.  But the object itself is part of the parent object's time-travel setting.  See what happens when you make me think on a Sunday?  :-)

Comment: Yeah, but if your parent has no TT, and your table has, you do not expect to lose all table data when you drop the table.